# Use props in composables vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am upgrading an app from vue 2 to vue 3 and I am having some issues with composables. I'd like to use props in the composable but it doesn't seem to be working. The code sample is pulled from a working component and works fine when I leave it in the component.

I assume `defineProps` isn't supported by composables, but then I am unclear how to handle it. When I pass the `src` in the parameters it loses its reactivity.

```js
// loadImage.js
import { defineProps, onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'

// by convention, composable function names start with "use"
export function useLoadImage() {
  let loadingImage = ref(true)
  let showImage = ref(false)
  const props = defineProps({
    src: String,
  })
  const delayShowImage = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      showImage.value = true
    }, 100)
  }
  const loadImage = (src) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = (e) => {
      loading.value = false
      img.onload = undefined
      img.src = undefined
      img = undefined
      delayShowImage()
    }
    img.src = src
  }
  onMounted(() => {
    if (props.src) {
      loadImage(props.src)
    }
  })
  watch(
    () => props.src,
    (val) => {
      if (val) {
        loadingImage.value = true
        loadImage(val)
      }
    },
  )
  // expose managed state as return value
  return { loadingImage, showImage }
}
```

## Edit

This method worked for me, but the two methods mentioned in the comments below did not.

I have a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409932/passing-a-single-property-to-a-composable-in-vue3).

```js
// loadImage.js
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'

// by convention, composable function names start with "use"
export function useLoadImage(props) {
  let loadingImage = ref(true)
  let showImage = ref(false)

  const delayShowImage = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      showImage.value = true
    }, 100)
  }
  const loadImage = (src) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = (e) => {
      loading.value = false
      img.onload = undefined
      img.src = undefined
      img = undefined
      delayShowImage()
    }
    img.src = src
  }
  onMounted(() => {
    if (props.src) {
      loadImage(props.src)
    }
  })
  watch(
    () => props.src,
    (val) => {
      if (val) {
        loadingImage.value = true
        loadImage(val)
      }
    },
  )
  // expose managed state as return value
  return { loadingImage, showImage }
}
```

```js
<script setup>
import { defineProps, toRef } from 'vue'
import { useLoadImage } from '../../composables/loadImage'

const props = defineProps({
  src: String
})
const { loading, show } = useLoadImage(props)

</script>
```

Comment: How exactly does it lose reactivity? Please, clarify what is the current behaviour and what you expect. Notice that you use script setup, not regular composition api. There is no `src` variable so  return `{ loadingImage, showImage, src }` will cause an error

Comment: @EstusFlask The src was a typo from an earlier version, I removed it. I was calling `const {loadingImage, showImage} = useLoadImage(props.src)` and src would not update once the property was set. passing in the entire props object solved the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) :

> `defineProps` and `defineEmits` are compiler macros only usable inside `<script setup>`

You should pass the `props` as parameter without destructing them to not lose the reactivity :

```js
export function useLoadImage(props) {
....

}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I was calling `const {loadingImage, showImage} 
= useLoadImage(props.src)` and that did not work. Passing the props object worked well. Thank you.

Comment: It's an antipattern to pass the whole object that can be accessed in arbitrary way. A more correct way is to make useLoadImage accept a ref, i.e. `srcRef = computed(() => props.src)`

Comment: That's a cleaner way specially for parameters typing, but I see in Vuetify 3 code source they pass the whole props to composables https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/next/packages/vuetify/src/components/VBtn/VBtn.tsx

Comment: @EstusFlask that definitely cleaner. I wonder why the Vuetify folks are doing it that way, saving space?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, that's an example of questionable code. When a hook changes the way it works with props, it needs extra care for all places where they are passed, and vice versa. But Vuetify uses TS so it makes it's easier to maintain.

Comment: @whoacowboy It's more performant by nature without bunch of computeds that Vuetify component would require. Not sure if there's a bottleneck they tried to avoid this way, but any way, that's one of concerns here

Comment: @EstusFlask but I think `srcRef = toRef(props.src)` it's better than `srcRef = computed(() => props.src)`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I use computeds where possible to avoid accidental writes to readonly properties, but yes, that's a matter of taste most times.

Comment: I think you can do `const { props } = getCurrentInstance()`. guess it needs script setup too.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim So i tried both `const srcRef = toRef(props.src)`and `srcRef = computed(() => props.src)` and neither worked. I am using `<script setup>` and `props.src` is `undefined`. I asked a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409932/passing-a-single-property-to-a-composable-in-vue3

Comment: @EstusFlask this makes sense as a anti-pattern.. is there anywhere a guide to composition based anti patterns?

Answer (score 30):

Your assumption is correct that `defineProps` cannot be used in composables!
But the question is:

#### How to pass props into composables without losing reactivity:

##### ❓ Pass the whole `props` object

```js
const props = defineProps({ src: string })

useFeature(props)
```

If you pass the whole props object, reactivity will be retained! However, I don't recommend doing that because:

1. The composable doesn't need all the props
2. If it needs ALL the props then probably you should split that composable into smaller ones

In general keep your composables as simple as they can be

##### ❓ Use `toRef`

One solution people use, is `toRef`:

```js
const props = defineProps({ foo: Object })

useFeature(toRef(props, 'foo'))
```

This might work in most cases, however there are two problems:

1. `props.foo` may not exist when `toRef` is called
2. This cannot handle the case when `props.foo` is swapped to a different object.

##### ❓ Use `computed`

This is the most common solution devs use:

```js
const props = defineProps({ foo: Object })

useFeature(computed(() => props.foo?.bar))
```

However, using computed is sub-optimal here. Internally, computed creates a separate effect to cache the computation. **computed is an overkill for simple getters that just access properties.**

##### ❓✅ Use `toRefs`

```js
const props = defineProps({ src: string })

const { src } = toRefs(props)
useFeature(src)
```

This works very well but starting from 3.3 we would have [reactive `defineProps`](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/502) so it would be unnecessary to use `toRefs` on props.

I would think of it as a legacy code starting from 3.3.

##### ✅ Use "thunking"

The least expensive way to pass non-ref reactive state into a composable is by wrapping it with a getter (or "thunking" - i.e. delaying the access of the actual value until the getter is called):

```js
const props = defineProps({ foo: Object })

useFeature(() => props.foo?.bar)
```

In this way, reactivity will be retained! Here is an example on how to use this inside composables:

```js
import { computed, watch } from 'vue'

export function useFeature(imageSrc) { 
  const newImageSrc = computed(() => `https:\\${imageSrc()}`) //  access it

  watch(imageSrc, (newVal) => { ... } //  watch it
  
  return { ... }
}
```

---

[Checkout a demo in Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9U02L2zAQ/SuDKcSBWIK2UDDJsmWh0Fvplp50WNeeJGqtDyQ5aTH+7x3JseukbG7WvJn3PG9m+uyjtezUYVZmW187aQN4DJ19EFoqa1yAHhzuYYC9MwpWlLqaoSej7CXOeHxEJoIBhK6N9gGkqg747GrYRZZ81eC+6tqwWgu95aMeKdEjoLJtFZBeANtEXKbiwrt6J7KJSGQi8DHp6GD8ejpW+oAgQwlbqW0X4FQo02B7VUepWz7LZBuCYhOFqiz76Y0mB/r06xfAi6yEFIkxaiy+RXYMwfqS807bXwdWG8UfCeOu00EqLBqjHt+xt+z9B95IH5Zxhl4VP5w5e3SkKLLNgpxT8ISucKgbdOjuit3kXgneYP+JRs1B6IEM6Dx+wip0Dgmh9pcD3wCpkZXYbOBchfp4swFC4++Uve90HaTR8I8tn0xfE1fUu+yCDuh01X6v2mkdtEnrBn8wrUTcGxjlZo4N5BrPVLOG3cM0jwUVO1Vth0Q4ZqX2ZipHq+x0rBJBBIXeE2k5t5bnifTl25G2J+oBLRtIX8KbftLP1wOLVJ+jJGmRRoJv/2B4SaoXa6djuHdWwXx97bD6hZtzBuNXA7u6M+uM9WQC3ZfU+CW+8n6+vhKeg5P6kJyZSnq4+EECu+X0RlMSI5snef9erRs/+gUpOUEIH6Hl5Q1/AeSriwE=)

#### Future improvements

In [this PR](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/7997), *from which this answer is heavily inspired*, we will have the ability to use `toRef` with a getter syntax like:

```
toRef(() => object.key)
```

So when 3.3 is released the best way to do it will be:

##### ✅✅ Use `toRef` with a getter

```js
const props = defineProps({ foo: Object })

useFeature(toRef(() => props.foo?.bar))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useRef` to pass specific props without losing reactivity

```
const imgRef = toRef(props, "img");
const { loding, show } = useLoadImage(imgRef);
```