# Passing a single property to a composable in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am using a composable to load images in Vue3. I have been able to pass all the props successfully as one object, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408463/use-props-in-composables-vue3/72408617), but I am unable to pass the one property I want to be reactive. I am fairly certain that the issue is that the property in undefined

```js
// loadImage.js
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'

// by convention, composable function names start with "use"
export function useLoadImage(src) {
  let loading = ref(true)
  let show = ref(false)

  const delayShowImage = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      show.value = true
    }, 100)
  }
  const loadImage = (src) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = (e) => {
      loading.value = false
      img.onload = undefined
      img.src = undefined
      img = undefined
      delayShowImage()
    }
    img.src = src
  }
  onMounted(() => {
    if (src) {
      loadImage(src)
    }
  })
  watch(
    () => src,
    (val) => {
      if (val) {
        loading.value = true
        loadImage(val)
      }
    },
  )
  // expose managed state as return value
  /**
   * loading is the image is loading
   * show is a delayed show for images that transition.
   */
  return { loading, show }
}
```

The below method returns this in the console.log and does not error.

`Proxy {src: undefined} undefined`

```html
<script setup>
import { defineProps, computed } from 'vue'
import { useLoadImage } from '../../composables/loadImage'

const props = defineProps({
  src: String
})

console.log(props, props.src)
const srcRef = computed(() => props.src)
const { loading, show } = useLoadImage(srcRef)
</script>
```

The below method returns this in the console.log

`Proxy {src: undefined} undefined`

and gives the following error

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')`

```html
<script setup>
import { defineProps, toRef } from 'vue'
import { useLoadImage } from '../../composables/loadImage'

const props = defineProps({
  src: String
})

console.log(props, props.src)
const srcRef = toRef(props.src)
const { loading, show } = useLoadImage(srcRef)
</script>
```

Comment: It seems you're not passing the `src` props correctly to the component which is why it's returning undefined

Comment: @ibn_Abubakre The issue then is that it is not reactive. When the src updates, the composable does not.

Comment: See answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196045/6385184

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated in comments, it seems `src` is `undefined` in your component because you're probably not passing the prop correctly to the component.

Even if `src` were set with a string, there still would be a few other issues:

1. [`toRef`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref)'s first argument should be a `reactive` object (i.e., `props`), and the second argument should be the name of a key (i.e., `'src'`):

   ```js
   // MyComponent.vue

   const srcRef = toRef(props.src) ❌
   const srcRef = toRef(props, 'src') ✅
   ```

   **Note:** It's also valid to use `const srcRef = computed(() => props.src)`, as you were originally doing.
2. [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch)'s first argument is a `WatchSource`. When `WatchSource` is a function dealing with a `ref`, it should return the `ref`'s unwrapped value. Alternatively, the `WatchSource` can be the `ref` itself:

   ```js
   // loadImage.js

   watch(() => srcRef, /* callback */) ❌
   watch(() => srcRef.value, /* callback */) ✅
   watch(srcRef, /* callback */) ✅
   ```
3. The composable receives the image source in a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), and your `onMounted()` hook is passing that `ref` to `loadImage()`, which is actually expecting the string in the `ref`'s unwrapped value:

   ```js
   // loadImage.js

   onMounted(() => {
     if (src) { ❌ /* src is a ref in this composable */
       loadImage(src)
     }
   })

   onMounted(() => {
     if (src.value) { ✅
       loadImage(src.value)
     }
   })
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-pass-prop-ref-to-composable?file=src%2Fcomposables%2FuseLoadImage.js)